# Simple R question - how to use a loop correctly

Tags: html, r, loops, web-scraping

I would first like to preface this question by saying I am new to R and would really appreciate any help this community can provide:

Context: I am trying to make this loop go through and read the first data table from a website (https://www.footballdb.com/college-football/teams/fbs/oklahoma/stats/2010.html"), for the years 2010-2019, and then save that data in its own individual table. However, I have been unable to do so, as I don't think I have a firm understanding of how to properly use the loop itself.

My current code:

```
        for(i in 2010:2019)
{
pageurl <-paste("https://www.footballdb.com/college-football/teams/fbs/oklahoma/stats/",i,".html")

content <- read_html(pageurl)

tables[i] <- content %>% html_table(fill = TRUE)
Passing_Table[i] <- tables[[1]]
Passing_Table$year <- i
}*
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `paste` is introducing spaces in your URLs. It might be informative to look at `pageurl` and copy it (verbatim) into a web browser to see if the URL is actually formated correctly. Instead, use `paste0(...)` or `paste(..., sep = "")` (identical).

Comment: Also, when you have problems with `for` loops, run smaller loops. In your case, `for(i in 2010:2010)` and go from there. Tip: after the loop, `tables` is `NULL`, something went wrong.